# Почему перестали ставить запятые после вводных конструкций перед союзами?

Tags: запятые, вставная-конструкция

Я привожу цитаты из вполне приличной детской книги известного автора  Холли Вебб, представленную известным издательством "Эксмо".

**Почему перед союзами ЧТО и НО нет запятых?** Я полагаю, что это не ошибка редактора, а вполне обдуманный шаг. Может быть, есть какие-то новые правила, которые применяются пока неофициально? Или это особенные вставки (с союзами в начале)?

(1) *Когда они не замечали её, она старательно притворялась — **в том числе и перед самой собой** — что ей все равно.*

2) *Конечно, всем хотелось верить, что они не служили Талису - **как уверял император** - но если бы их замысел осуществился...*

Comment: Похоже на симметрию. Розенталь ведь её не запрещает. А чего нет запятой после "*конечно*"?

Comment: Розенталь другую симметрию разрешает: выделение вводной конструкции тире и запятой с обеих сторон. Кстати, я полагаю, что разрешение это условное, так как в действительности симметричная конструкция имеет конкретный смысл. Запятую же  я случайно не поставила, пока переписывала это длинное предложение (скопировать его не удалось).

Comment: Интересно, какой конкретный смысл может быть у симметричной конструкции?

Comment: А это пока секрет, подумайте сами.

Comment: Без понятия, так как симметрия в моём понимании - это лишь графика.

Comment: Значит, пересмотрите свое понимание. Выглядит как графика, но влияет на смысл и интонацию. С этого и начните, всегда вам нужно подсказывать.

Comment: Ни разу не помню, чтобы вы подсказывали. Пауза больше. На смысл - это что-то новенькое.

Comment: Да ладно, шуток не понимаете. Я тут взялась за серьезный анализ вводных конструкций  и, кажется, догадалась, в чем тайна симметрии. А сейчас другие дела  отвлекли меня  от этой темы, я сразу и не вспомню, надо заново всё продумывать. Но вы тоже можете этим заняться.

Comment: Розенталь не догадался, а вы догадались...

Comment: Он тоже догадался, но не стал перегружать вас дополнительными знаниями. Считал, что вы и эти-то не усвоите.

Answer (score 1):

В первом предложении - грубая (для печатного текста) ошибка в употреблении выражения "в том числе": ему должно предшествовать напр. "(притворялась) *перед всеми* (или иной группой людей)" - в качестве общего понятия, на которое этим выражением ссылаются. Вряд ли эту распространённую небрежность успели легализовать. После исправления можно было бы и запятую поставить. Стало быть, и переводчики, наряду с беззащитными телезрителями, стали в письменной форме подражать участникам политических дебатов и спортивным комментаторам. Во втором предложении запятая явно требуется - похоже на редакторский просмотр.

Comment: Насчет ошибки я не очень понимаю. Обычно человек притворяется перед другими, это и так  очевидно, но себя обманывает не всегда. Мне же не нравится рифмованное сочетание "перед самой собой". Можно сказать как-то иначе?

Comment: Практически любым выражением можно заменить (даже, к тому же...) - говорящий не понимает разницы между выражениями "в частности" и "в том числе" (это выражение не является идиомой и должно ссылаться на ранее названное "то, в числе чего"), и машинально воспроизводит ходячие небрежности устной речи. Даже в современном словаре Ефремовой об этом есть: _Употребляется при присоединении члена предложения_, который является частью **целого (о котором говорится в первой части предложения)**.  _соответствуя по значению сл.: включая кого-либо или что-либо, в том числе и._

Answer (score 1):

Издательство "Эксмо" никогда не славилось грамотностью. Лично видел примеры, когда ошибка кочует из книги в книгу, минуя несколько "стадий корректуры", вероятно, номинальных. Так что никогда не полагайтесь на это издательство (и многие другие) по части грамотности. Не Советский Союз у нас. Издательский процесс обеспечивают студенты-фрилансеры. Всем движет скорость и экономия.
Естественно, в каждом из этих примеров запятые нужны. Никакое тире их не съедает, никакой авторской пунктуации там нет. Всё, что есть, это халтура и лень.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А каким издательствам Вы доверяете?

Comment: "Ладомир", конечно же

Comment: Из крохотных ещё "Додо пресс", но даже у них в "Островитянине", к сожалению, были ошибки.